# Form with multiple email fields to multiple recipients

Tags: php, html, forms, email

This is my html form. The user will input the email addresses he/she would like to send the html email to.

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="">
<table width="400">
  <tr>
    <td>Please enter your email address:</td>
    <td<input type="text" name="email" id="email" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Please enter the email addresses you would like to notify below:</td>
    <td>
      &nbsp;
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Email:</td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="email1" id="email1" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Email:</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="email2" id="email2" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Email:</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="email3" id="email3" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Email:</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="email4" id="email4" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
</form>
```

This is somewhat the php code.

```
<?php 
$ToEmail = '["email1"]["email2"]["email3"]["email4"]'; 
$EmailSubject = 'Check this out guys!'; 
$mailheader = "From: ".$_POST["email"]."\r\n"; 
$mailheader .= "Reply-To: "noreply@domain.com"\r\n"; 
$mailheader .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";  
mail(......) or die ("Failure"); 
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
    alert("Success! You have sent the notification to the emails you have entered.");
    <!--
    window.location = "form.html"
    //-->
  </script>
```

How do I:

1. Modify the PHP code so that it will send to the emails inputed by the user?

2. The body message of the notification is a html email. How do I go about adding it to the PHP code?

Your help is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you need to $_POST the email1, email2 etc. values to a variable then use that as your value for $to in the `mail()` function - just make sure you add a comma after each:

```
$to = $_POST['email1'] . ', ';
$to .= $_POST['email2'] . ', ';
$to .= $_POST['email3'];
```

etc. Leave off the comma for the last email and you should be ready to go.

Regarding the content of your email, you should be able to send html no problem - just store it in a variable for ease of use later, e.g:

```
$message = '
<html>
  <head>
    <title>This is the HTML Email</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="container">
      <p>Welcome to the html!</p>
      <img src="../img/some_image.jpg" alt="some image"/>
    </div>        
  </body>
</html>
';
```

then make sure you add the relevant HTML headers:

```
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
```

Along with any other headers e.g.:

```
$headers .= 'From: HTML Email <you@example.com>' . "\r\n";
```

Then call `mail()` with your defined variables:

```
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Hope that helps.

p.s. its all available on the mail function definition: [`mail()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php)

Comment: great answer! except that I wouldn't want the recipients to see the email 'To:' field as To: you@example.com, hello@example.com, hi@example.com I just want them to see their own email at the 'To:' field

Comment: A quick google search turned up this post, http://www.pear-forum.org/topic2410.html, which is interesting. I'd recommend the last option, which is to supply the To: header as your own name/email address (address of the sender) - I see this done a lot in newsletters I receive. `$headers .= 'To: Your Name <your@email.com>' . "\r\n";`

Answer (score 0):

Look at [the php manual for `mail`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php)

Example:

```
$toemails = "user@example.com, anotheruser@example.com";
```

Comment: The $toemails are not specified by the developer, the users will determine who the emails should be sent to as per the form.